# Column of Listtile with rounded corner at beginning and end

Tags: flutter, border, listtile

I'm trying to have a column of list tiles where the top and bottom corners are rounded. Some tiles change colors when hovered and other don't. Hence, I have tried to two things:

- Create a container with rounded corners, add a Column inside with my listTiles.
- Create a column with my list tiles, and add specific rounded countainers for the first and last element.
- Color the container that hold all elements. The problem then is that the hover color of the listtiles is painted under that of the container.

Sadly, in both cases, the background color of the list tile overflow from the rounded container as seen in this image:

[image: Example result]

Here is the sample code for the second try:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final children = List<Widget>.generate(
      5,
      (i) => ListTile(
          tileColor: Colors.green, hoverColor: Colors.red, title: Text('$i')));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: List.generate(
        children.length,
        (index) {
          if (index == 0 && index == children.length - 1) {
            return Ink(
              // clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              child: children[index],
            );
          }
          if (index == 0) {
            return Container(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              child: children[index],
            );
          } else if (index == children.length - 1) {
            return Container(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              child: children[index],
            );
          }

          return children[index];
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Where `children` is a list of listile and other elements.

How can a force element in `children` to respect the border limits set up by the parent container?

Comment: you want above type of widget red container

Comment: I want the corner of list tiles, in grey, to not be outside of the red border on top and bottom

Comment: instead of cornering the 1st and last item, enclose the column with ClipRRect with corner borders

Comment: Tested with ClipRRect and still it doesn't work. I filled an issue on the github repo: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94785

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have ended-up posting an [Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94785) on Github.

The solution a `Card` with `clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias`.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias` to your `Container`.

### Code sample

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final children = List<Widget>.generate(5, (i) => ListTile(title: Text('$i')));
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: List.generate(
        children.length,
        (index) {
          if (index == 0 && index == children.length - 1) {
            return Container(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias, // here
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              child: children[index],
            );
          }
          if (index == 0) {
            return Container(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias, // here
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              child: children[index],
            );
          } else if (index == children.length - 1) {
            return Container(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias, // and here
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              child: children[index],
            );
          }

          return children[index];
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

[Try the full code on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=35da134d6710a3b50e272b92dde4f122)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sadly, it doesn't solve my use case. I have updated my original post using your code sample to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the rounded corners by adding a `shape` property in `ListTile`.

```
ListTile(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(25),
                   ),
                 ),
          tileColor: Colors.indigo,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          iconColor: Colors.white,
          leading: Icon(Icons.light),
          title: Text('List Tile 2'),
          subtitle: Text('This is a subtitle'),
        ),
```